# Change Ansible key in a dict

Tags: ansible

I have a dictionary in Ansible.

```
my_dict:
  key1 : value1
  key2 : value2
  key3 : value3
  key4 : value4
```

I would like the final output to be

```
my_dict:
  key1 : value1
  key2 : value2
  key33 : value3
  key4 : value4
```

Is there a way to change the dictionary key from key3 to key33 ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Q: ***"Is there a way to change the dictionary key from key3 to key33?"***

A: No. There is not. A new dictionary must be created. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_dict:
      key1 : value1
      key2 : value2
      key3 : value3
      key4 : value

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        my_dict2: "{{ my_dict2|default({})|
                      combine({my_dict_trans[item.key]|
                               default(item.key): item.value}) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_dict|dict2items }}"
      vars:
        my_dict_trans:
          key3: key33

    - debug:
        var: my_dict2
```

gives

```yaml
  my_dict2:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key33: value3
    key4: value4
```

---

**Update**

- It's possible to avoid the iteration in a task. The below declarations give the same result

```yaml
  my_dict_trans:
    key3: key33

  my_dict2: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for k,v in my_dict.items() %}
    {{ my_dict_trans[k]|d(k) }}: {{ v }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

- The next and simplest option is the filter [ansible.utils.replace_keys](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/replace_keys_filter.html#ansible-utils-replace-keys-filter-replaces-specific-keys-with-their-after-value-from-a-data-recursively). This filter requires as a parameter list of the dictionaries. You can write it or convert the dictionary *my_dict_trans*

```yaml
  my_dict_target: "{{ my_dict_trans|
                      dict2items(key_name='before',
                                 value_name='after') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_dict_target:
    - {after: key33, before: key3}
```

Then, the below declaration gives also the same result

```yaml
  my_dict3: "{{ my_dict|
                ansible.utils.replace_keys(target=my_dict_target) }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_dict:
      key1 : value1
      key2 : value2
      key3 : value3
      key4 : value4

    my_dict_trans:
      key3: key33

    my_dict2: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for k,v in my_dict.items() %}
      {{ my_dict_trans[k]|d(k) }}: {{ v }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

    my_dict_target: "{{ my_dict_trans|
                        dict2items(key_name='before',
                                   value_name='after') }}"

    my_dict3: "{{ my_dict|
                  ansible.utils.replace_keys(target=my_dict_target) }}"
    
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_dict2

    - debug:
        var: my_dict_target|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: my_dict3
```